# remove xmlformatter for web forms app that is using web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have an existing .net web forms application.   I added web api to the project through nu get.   I added the routing information to global asax

so instead of the typical web api project where you have a  myproject.Config to 
add your routing

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I had to put it in global asax under application_start

```
  System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

that works and everything is working great however for some browsers the response is being returned as xml and I would like it to always be JSON so typically to achieve this in a regular web api project in the myproject Config I add.

```
 config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

I can't figure out how to do that in the global asax version of my configuration  I tried

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Remove(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

but it complains that formatters is not a member of System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I just found it. it is

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear()
```

sorry about that should have looked around a little more before posting